# HttpClient fails when vpn is turned on

Tags: vb.net, http

Reading a web server on a microcontroller (Esp32) from a Visual Basic program running on Windows 11, using HttpClient works perfectly UNTIL I turn on my VPN (HMA). I am using the synchronous method of HttpClient.send. If I read the same webserver using a browser (Edge) everything works fine with the VPN on or off, so I guess I need to modify the HttpClient request but how?

When the VPN turns on I get
"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (192.168.100.21:80)" "SocketErrorCode AccessDenied {10013} System.Net.Sockets.SocketError"

Here is my code

```
Function Esp32Request(URL As String) As String
    'next line is in form1.load, so only called once
    'Shared ReadOnly client As New HttpClient()

    ' URL example is "http://192.168.100.21/temperature"

    Try
        Dim infoRequest As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL)
        Dim response = client.Send(infoRequest)
        Dim responseAsStream As Stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream()
        Dim responseAsStreamreader As New StreamReader(responseAsStream)
        Dim responseText As String = responseAsStreamreader.ReadToEnd()
        Return responseText
    Catch e As Exception
        Dim tmpStr As String = ErrorDate & " [Esp32Request] " & vbCrLf
        tmpStr &= e.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Call LogErrors(tmpStr)
        Return "0.00"
    End Try
End Function
```

I have searched the web for days and although there are many reports of this socket error occurring with a vpn, I cannot find a solution other than "turn the vpn off"

Comment: This sounds like a networking routing issue rather than VB.NET issue. If the network you are connecting to is on 192.168.x.x local subnet, you could try changing your home network router to use 172.16.x.x local subnet instead.